# What is the Spring equivalent of this native Mongo aggregation pipeline?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation

I am having the following native Mongo aggregation pipeline, which delivers exactly what I need.

```js
db.getCollection('CONFIG').aggregate([
    {'$match': {_id: 'COLLECTIONS_META'}},
    {'$unwind': '$value'},
    {'$group': {'_id': 'COLLECTION_NAMES', 'value': {'$push': '$value.suffix'}}}
])
```

However, as I am having to write this in a Spring aggregation pipeline, all I could come up with is following.

```java
Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("_id")
        .is("COLLECTIONS_META")),
    Aggregation.unwind("value"),
    Aggregation.group().push("value.suffix").as("value"),
    Aggregation.project("value")
        .and("COLLECTION_NAMES")
        .asLiteral()
        .as("_id")
);
```

As you can see, this is literally not the **equivalent** of the native pipeline. This is evident, when the Spring pipeline is converted to its native counterpart.

```json
{
   "aggregate":"__collection__",
   "pipeline":[
      {
         "$match":{
            "_id":"COLLECTIONS_META"
         }
      },
      {
         "$unwind":"$value"
      },
      {
         "$group":{
            "_id":null,
            "value":{
               "$push":"$value.suffix"
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "$project":{
            "value":1,
            "_id":{
               "$literal":"COLLECTION_NAMES"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

What am I missing? I'd like to omit the projection that I am doing at the end of the Spring version of the pipeline.

Comment: You can use annotation `@Aggregation` of Spring Data MongoDB API.

Comment: @prasad_ Thanks for the suggestion. But it wouldn't work in my case...